# GET method with many parameters by rest

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, restful-url

I have class

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class TransactionRequest {
  private String p1;
  private String p2;
  private String p3;
}
```

I have rest method

```
@Slf4j
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/transactions")
public class TransactionsController {

  ...

  @PostMapping(value = "/page/{page}")
  public TransactionsResponse transactions(@RequestBody TransactionRequest transactionRequest,
    @PathVariable int page) {
    return transactionsService.getTransactions(transactionRequest, page);
```

I pass 3 parameters in Body. But logically if I need all transactions I need call GET method. And  change URL to

`@GetMapping(value = "/{p1}/{p2}/{p3}/page/{page}")`

but I if I need large filter for request I need pass many parameters in url.

How in general is it correct to do this by rest?

Comment: depends on the use-cass but what about one parameter and pass multpile values?

Comment: Either try to pass the values in the request URL as a GET, or if the request become too big to process, the use the POST body as you indicated, no real other way to do it.  The only other thing I can think of is minifying the parameters if possible or mapping short key/values so you don't pass a massive GET request.